# Which is the entry file used by vue-cli-service?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Got a project using `vue`, `webpack`, `babel`, `npm`.
Could start it via `npm run server`, when trying to figure out how this command work, I saw `vue-cli-service serve` from package.json.

But, how does `vue-cli-service` start the program? I saw `main.js` which in turn render `Vue.vue`, both of which are under `src/`.

Didn't see anywhere config the entry file, so is `main.js` the default entry for `vue-cli-service`?

---

### Code

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "quizer-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "element-ui": "^2.10.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: show us your `package.json`.

Comment: @YongQuan Added.

Comment: The command resolves [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vue-cli-service` uses Webpack with a default configuration of

```js
entry: {
  app: [
    './src/main.js'
  ]
}
```

This can be altered in `vue.config.js` if you wish. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration

Webpack will build a JS bundle, starting at the *entry* then inject that into the `index.html` file and that's how your app starts.

You can see the entire configuration for your app using

```sh
vue inspect
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config

Answer (score 5):

It is hardcoded in `@vue`.

Relative Path: `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js`

Line 28-37:

```js
    webpackConfig
      .mode('development')
      .context(api.service.context)
      .entry('app')
        .add('./src/main.js')
        .end()
      .output
        .path(api.resolve(options.outputDir))
        .filename(isLegacyBundle ? '[name]-legacy.js' : '[name].js')
        .publicPath(options.publicPath)
```